# Need to integrate Splunk with Git such that Splunk can clone and commit to Git

Tags: git, automation, configuration, splunk, observability

If Splunk detects certain events, it needs to trigger cloning, committing, and creating a pull request on Git.

I can find add-ons on Splunkbase that let me send data from Git to Splunk, but is there anything that lets Splunk send commands to Git?